# Collecting IO outputs into list

Tags: haskell, io, monads

How can I issue multiple calls to [`SDL.pollEvent :: IO Event`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/SDL/0.6.2/doc/html/Graphics-UI-SDL-Events.html#v%3ApollEvent) until the output is `SDL.NoEvent` and collect all the results into a list?

In imperative terms something like this:

```
events = []
event = SDL.pollEvent
while ( event != SDL.NoEvent ) {
        events.add( event )
        event = SDL.pollEvent
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

James Cook was so kind to extend [monad-loop](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-loops/0.3.1.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Loops.html)s with this function:

```
unfoldWhileM  :: Monad  m => (a -> Bool) -> m a -> m [a]
```

used with SDL:

```
events <- unfoldWhileM (/= SDL.NoEvent) SDL.pollEvent
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like:

```
takeWhileM :: (a -> Bool) -> IO a -> IO [a]
takeWhileM p act = do
  x <- act
  if p x
    then do
      xs <- takeWhileM p act
      return (x : xs)
    else
      return []
```

Instead of:

```
do
  xs <- takeWhileM p act
  return (x : xs)
```

you can also use:

`liftM (x:) (takeWhileM p act)` yielding:

```
takeWhileM :: (a -> Bool) -> IO a -> IO [a]
takeWhileM p act = do
  x <- act
  if p x
    then liftM (x:) (takeWhileM p act)
    else return []
```

Then you can use: `takeWhileM (/=SDL.NoEvent) SDL.pollEvent`

Comment: I'd suggest `takeUntilM :: Monad m => (a -> Bool) -> m a -> m [a]` (with appropriate `return [x]` when `p x` is `false`) to avoid information loss (especially from IO monads). That may look normal when it just `SDL.NoEvent` but it might be wrong for `Left "system crash" :: Either String a`.

Comment: Oh, and you probably want to build lazy list, so need to use `interleaveIO` from `System.Unsafe` (or something like that). I.e. something like `liftM (x:) (interleaveIO (unsafeTakeUntilM p act))`

Comment: A lot of variants of `takeWhileM`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133800/haskell-monadic-takewhile/1138153#1138153

Comment: `spanM` looks nice. So `curry (liftM fst . uncurry (flip (flip spanM . repeat)))` :)

Comment: @peaker: imho using monadic lists is more modular

Comment: @ony: Why lazy? This is polling events in the main loop of an SDL application. Logically, it's better to think of SDL pushing events to the program, not the program pulling events on demand. In fact, I think SDL will fall over if you don't clear the event queue quickly enough. Sometimes laziness doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ony: lazy-IO is bug prone. But if one would still insist on doing it, I don't think that creating a lazy `IO` version of `takeWhileM` is a nice and modular approach. Transforming to a lazy list should be done as a separate step from `takeWhile`. this could be achieved using monadic lists. (shameless plug for my own answer below)

Comment: i actually want poll all events away from at the start of a gameloop iteration, so the IO stuff doesn't interfere with the functional game logic

Comment: @camccann: I don't think that leaving general memory overflow (because of list growing faster than consumers process it) resolving to the Haskell system is a good idea. I guess, SDL will have more specific way of handling event queue overflow (reducing frames, dropping interval timeouts, skipping mouse positions, beeping on key pressings etc). I agree that lazy list bug prone and it's better to do some kind of `mapSDLEvents_ :: (Event -> IO ()) -> IO ()` or `foldSDLEvents :: (a -> Event -> IO a) -> a -> IO a`. @yairchu: yes `spanM :: (a -> Bool) -> [m a] -> m ([a], [m a])` is good for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use monadic lists:

```
import Control.Monad.ListT (ListT)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift) -- transformers, not mtl
import Data.List.Class (takeWhile, repeat, toList)
import Prelude hiding (takeWhile, repeat)

getEvents :: IO [Event]
getEvents = 
    toList . takeWhile (/= NoEvent) $ do
        repeat ()
        lift pollEvent :: ListT IO Event
```

`ListT` from the "List" package on hackage.

Comment: @peaker: `repeat () :: ListT IO ()` is an infinite IO-monadic list containing values that don't matter (`()`). then we `(>>)` it with `lift pollEvent` so that for each element of the infinite list we `pollEvent`. `takeWhile` makes it a finite monadic list and then `toList` makes it `:: IO [Event]`.

Comment: That seems a bit weird.. Maybe makes more sense to use something like "repeatM (lift pollEvent)" ?

Comment: @peaker: yeah, `repeatM pollEvent`. I added `repeatM` to the github tree and it will be there in the next hackage version

Answer (score 1):

Using these stubs for `Event` and `pollEvent`

```
data Event = NoEvent | SomeEvent
  deriving (Show,Eq)

instance Random Event where
  randomIO = randomRIO (0,1) >>= return . ([NoEvent,SomeEvent] !!)

pollEvent :: IO Event
pollEvent = randomIO
```

and a combinator, borrowed and adapted from [an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133800/haskell-monadic-takewhile/1138153#1138153), that stops evaluating the first time the predicate fails

```
spanM :: (Monad m) => (a -> Bool) -> m a -> m [a]
spanM p a = do
  x <- a
  if p x then do xs <- spanM p a
                 return (x:xs)
         else return [x]
```

allows this ghci session, for example:

```
*Main> spanM (/= NoEvent) pollEvent 
[SomeEvent,SomeEvent,NoEvent]
```

Answer (score 0):

i eventually stumbled over this code snippet in an actual SDL game from hackage

```
getEvents :: IO Event -> [Event] -> IO [Event]
getEvents pEvent es = do
  e <- pEvent
  let hasEvent = e /= NoEvent
  if hasEvent
   then getEvents pEvent (e:es)
   else return (reverse es)
```

thanks for your answers btw!

Comment: If that is so popular approach to pull out all events waiting in queue in one shot without processing it, than why SDL API doesn't provide it directly? That may help to avoid some sync. overhead for thread-safe queue.