# How do I handle an infinite list of IO objects in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, io, monads, infinite-loop, lazy-evaluation

I'm writing a program that reads from a list of files.  The each file either contains a link to the next file or marks that it's the end of the chain.

Being new to Haskell, it seemed like the idiomatic way to handle this is is a lazy list of possible files to this end, I have

```
getFirstFile :: String -> DataFile
getNextFile :: Maybe DataFile -> Maybe DataFile

loadFiles :: String -> [Maybe DataFile]
loadFiles = iterate getNextFile . Just . getFirstFile

getFiles :: String -> [DataFile]
getFiles = map fromJust . takeWhile isJust . loadFiles
```

So far, so good.  The only problem is that, since getFirstFile and getNextFile both need to open files, I need their results to be in the IO monad.  This gives the modified form of

```
getFirstFile :: String -> IO DataFile
getNextFile :: Maybe DataFile -> IO (Maybe DataFile)

loadFiles :: String -> [IO Maybe DataFile]
loadFiles = iterate (getNextFile =<<) . Just . getFirstFile

getFiles :: String -> IO [DataFile]
getFiles = liftM (map fromJust . takeWhile isJust) . sequence . loadFiles
```

The problem with this is that, since iterate returns an infinite list, sequence becomes an infinite loop.  I'm not sure how to proceed from here.  Is there a lazier form of sequence that won't hit all of the list elements?  Should I be rejiggering the map and takeWhile to be operating inside the IO monad for each list element?  Or do I need to drop the whole infinite list process and write a recursive function to terminate the list manually?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**A step in the right direction**

What puzzles me is `getNextFile`. Step into a simplified world with me, where we're not dealing with IO yet. The type is `Maybe DataFile -> Maybe DataFile`. In my opinion, this should simply be `DataFile -> Maybe DataFile`, and I will operate under the assumption that this adjustment is possible. And *that* looks like a good candidate for `unfoldr`. The first thing I am going to do is make my own simplified version of unfoldr, which is less general but simpler to use.

```
import Data.List

-- unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a,b)) -> b -> [a]
myUnfoldr :: (a -> Maybe a) -> a -> [a]
myUnfoldr f v = v : unfoldr (fmap tuplefy . f) v
  where tuplefy x = (x,x)
```

Now the type `f :: a -> Maybe a` matches `getNextFile :: DataFile -> Maybe DataFile`

```
getFiles :: String -> [DataFile]
getFiles = myUnfoldr getNextFile . getFirstFile
```

Beautiful, right? `unfoldr` is a lot like `iterate`, except once it hits `Nothing`, it terminates the list.

Now, we have a problem. `IO`. How can we do the same thing with `IO` thrown in there? Don't even *think* about The Function Which Shall Not Be Named. We need a beefed up unfoldr to handle this. Fortunately, the [source for unfoldr](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Data-List.html#unfoldr) is available to us.

```
unfoldr      :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]
unfoldr f b  =
  case f b of
   Just (a,new_b) -> a : unfoldr f new_b
   Nothing        -> []
```

Now what do we need? A healthy dose of `IO`. `liftM2 unfoldr` *almost* gets us the right type, but won't quite cut it this time.

**An actual solution**

```
unfoldrM :: Monad m => (b -> m (Maybe (a, b))) -> b -> m [a]
unfoldrM f b = do
  res <- f b
  case res of
    Just (a, b') -> do
      bs <- unfoldrM f b'
      return $ a : bs
    Nothing -> return []
```

It is a rather straightforward transformation; I wonder if there is some combinator that could accomplish the same.

Fun fact: we can now define `unfoldr f b = runIdentity $ unfoldrM (return . f) b`

Let's again define a simplified `myUnfoldrM`, we just have to sprinkle in a `liftM` in there:

```
myUnfoldrM :: Monad m => (a -> m (Maybe a)) -> a -> m [a]
myUnfoldrM f v = (v:) `liftM` unfoldrM (liftM (fmap tuplefy) . f) v
  where tuplefy x = (x,x)
```

And now we're all set, just like before.

```
getFirstFile :: String -> IO DataFile
getNextFile :: DataFile -> IO (Maybe DataFile)

getFiles :: String -> IO [DataFile]
getFiles str = do
  firstFile <- getFirstFile str
  myUnfoldrM getNextFile firstFile

-- alternatively, to make it look like before
getFiles' :: String -> IO [DataFile]
getFiles' = myUnfoldrM getNextFile <=< getFirstFile
```

By the way, I typechecked all of these with `data DataFile = NoClueWhatGoesHere`, and the type signatures for `getFirstFile` and `getNextFile`, with their definitions set to `undefined`.

---

[edit] changed `myUnfoldr` and `myUnfoldrM` to behave more like `iterate`, including the initial value in the list of results.

**[edit] Additional insight on unfolds:**

If you have a hard time wrapping your head around unfolds, the [Collatz sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) is possibly one of the simplest examples.

```
collatz :: Integral a => a -> Maybe a
collatz 1 = Nothing -- the sequence ends when you hit 1
collatz n | even n    = Just $ n `div` 2
          | otherwise = Just $ 3 * n + 1

collatzSequence :: Integral a => a -> [a]
collatzSequence = myUnfoldr collatz
```

Remember, `myUnfoldr` is a simplified unfold for the cases where the "next seed" and the "current output value" are the same, as is the case for collatz. This behavior should be easy to see given `myUnfoldr`'s simple definition in terms of `unfoldr` and `tuplefy x = (x,x)`.

```
ghci> collatzSequence 9
[9,28,14,7,22,11,34,17,52,26,13,40,20,10,5,16,8,4,2,1]
```

---

**More, mostly unrelated thoughts**

The rest has absolutely nothing to do with the question, but I just couldn't resist musing. We can define `myUnfoldr` in terms of `myUnfoldrM`:

```
myUnfoldr f v = runIdentity $ myUnfoldrM (return . f) v
```

Look familiar? We can even abstract this pattern:

```
sinkM :: ((a -> Identity b) -> a -> Identity c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
sinkM hof f = runIdentity . hof (return . f)

unfoldr = sinkM unfoldrM
myUnfoldr = sinkM myUnfoldrM
```

`sinkM` should work to "sink" (opposite of "lift") any function of the form

`Monad m => (a -> m b) -> a -> m c`.

since the `Monad m` in those functions can be unified with the `Identity` monad constraint of `sinkM`. However, [I don't see anything](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+m+b%29+-%3E+a+-%3E+m+c) that `sinkM` would actually be useful for.

Comment: Yes, this answer cures the disease instead of just treating the symptoms!

Comment: Important to note: `myUnfoldr` and `myUnfoldrM` will not keep the first file in the list; it is simply considered the seed to produce the rest of the list. This could easily be remedied if need be.

Comment: I couldn't find a combinator for `unfoldM` but I did manage to turn it into this totally incomprehensible one-liner: `unfoldrM f = (>>= maybe (return []) (uncurry $ \a -> liftM (a:) . unfoldrM f)) . f`

Comment: Since `(Identity.)` and `(runIdentity.)` convert between `a -> Identity b` and `a -> b` you can write `sinkM f = (runIdentity.) . f . (Identity.)`. Also note `sinkM mapM = map`, `sinkM filterM = filter`.

Comment: @sdcvvc Very cool, thanks for noticing! Interesting to note that the type signature I wrote for `sinkM` is too restrictive to use it for those. It should instead be `((a -> Identity b) -> a1 -> Identity c) -> (a -> b) -> a1 -> c`. In fact, using `return` instead of `Identity`, it is inferred to be even *more* generic.

Comment: Noticed today that unfoldrM is defined in [the monad-loops package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-loops/0.3/doc/html/Control-Monad-Loops.html).

Answer (score 10):

```
sequenceWhile :: Monad m => (a -> Bool) -> [m a] -> m [a]
sequenceWhile _ [] = return []
sequenceWhile p (m:ms) = do
  x <- m
  if p x
    then liftM (x:) $ sequenceWhile p ms
    else return []
```

---

Yields:

```
getFiles = liftM (map fromJust) . sequenceWhile isJust . loadFiles
```

Comment: Trying to google for `takeWhileM`, I have found a related question with code almost identical to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133800/haskell-monadic-takewhile/1134212#1134212

Comment: Haha, speaking of which, I recently added the monadlist package to hackage. It has a `takeWhileM` with `(a -> m a) -> [a] -> m [a]` (well, more general with MonadPlus return value). I'm going to have to add my `sequenceWhile` function in there and a `sequenceWhileM` (a -> m Bool).

Answer (score 9):

As you have noticed, IO results can't be lazy, so you can't (easily) build an infinite list using IO. There is a way out, however, in [`unsafeInterleaveIO`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v%3aunsafeInterleaveIO); with this, you can do something like:

```
ioList startFile = do
    v <- processFile startFile
    continuation <- unsafeInterleaveIO (nextFile startFile >>= ioList)
    return (v:continuation)
```

It's important to be careful here, though - you've just deferred the results of `ioList` to some unpredictable time in the future. It may never be run at all, in fact. So be very careful when you're being Clever™ like this.

Personally, I would just build a manual recursive function.

Answer (score 4):

Laziness and I/O are a tricky combination. Using `unsafeInterleaveIO` is one way to produce lazy lists in the IO monad (and this is the technique used by the standard `getContents`, `readFile` and friends). However, as convenient as this is, it exposes pure code to possible I/O errors and makes makes releasing resources (such as file handles) non-deterministic. This is why most "serious" Haskell applications (especially those concerned with efficiency) nowadays use things called Enumerators and Iteratees for streaming I/O. One library in Hackage that implements this concept is `enumerator`.

You are probably fine with using lazy I/O in your application, but I thought I'd still give this as an example of another way to approach these kind of problems. You can find more in-depth tutorials about iteratees [here](http://www.mew.org/~kazu/proj/enumerator/) and [here](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/enumerator).

For example, your stream of DataFiles could be implemented as an Enumerator like this:

```
import Data.Enumerator
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

iterFiles :: String -> Enumerator DataFile IO b
iterFiles s = first where
    first (Continue k) = do
        file <- liftIO $ getFirstFile s
        k (Chunks [file]) >>== next file
    first step = returnI step

    next prev (Continue k) = do
        file <- liftIO $ getNextFile (Just prev)
        case file of
            Nothing -> k EOF
            Just df -> k (Chunks [df]) >>== next df
    next _ step = returnI step
```