# how to lift find to use a -> IO Bool

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm basically looking for the `find` analogue of `filterM`:

```
findM :: (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m (Maybe a)
```

but I haven't been able to write it myself using `find` and some sort of lifting function. I'm currently doing it via `Data.Maybe.listToMaybe`:

```
x <- filterM f list
return $ listToMaybe x
```

which works, but it seems like I should be able to do it directly with `find`.

Edit: Found some stuff on hackage: [Control.Monad.Loops.firstM](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-loops/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Loops.html#v%3afirstM) and [Control.Monad.TM.findM](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/UtilityTM/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-TM.html#v%3afindM) both do what I want

Comment: Is the implementation in terms of `filterM` really what you want? Won't that result in the whole list being sequenced, even if the element is found right at the beginning?

Comment: yes, it's ideally not what i want, it just happens that for my program it doesn't make much difference. that's why i'd like to rewrite it properly to have the same semantics as find.

Comment: The [monad-loops package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops) has a `firstM` function of this type.  Note that when the predicate returns `True`, `firstM` does not apply it to subsequent items.

Comment: nice, firstM does just what i want. should have thought to check hayoo as well as hoogle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could write it "from scratch" like

```
findM p ls =
    case ls of
         []   -> return Nothing
         x:xs -> do
            ok <- p x
            if ok
               then return (Just x)
               else findM p xs
```

though I realize that is much less elegant than what you are asking for. I could not figure out how to do it with some sort of lifting function. I feel like the lifting would have to occur at the recursive step of `find`, which is hidden inside the function and not available to be lifted. Though I would love to see someone prove me wrong.

Comment: good point, i think you have put your finger on why lift doesn't work here. marking this as accepted.

Comment: There is no way to lift `find` to its counterpart `findM`, but there is a way to "sink" `findM` to its counterpart `find`, using `sinkM hof f = runIdentity . hof (return . f)`, you can `sinkM findM` and it will behave just like `find`, by running in the Identity monad. I wrote [sinkM a few months ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7735551/208257), just felt like sharing. I wonder if there's a package that provides this function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a boring, direct implementation:

```
findM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m (Maybe a)
findM _ []     = return Nothing
findM f (x:xs) = do
    found <- f x
    if found
        then return $ Just x
        else findM f xs
```

Notice that this `findM` does not apply `f` to any items after the found one.  Thus, it is semantically different from the `filterM` implementation you posted.

You can't write this based on `find` without going out of your way.  You already have a pure list, but the predicate `(a -> m Bool)` does not match the `(a -> Bool)` needed by `find`.  If you use `mapM` to apply the predicate to each item, all you get is `[Bool]`, which you would need to zip against the original list.